# Loop through custom fields with similar label / common chars in label

Tags: customization, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I created several custom fields for my custom post type "books"

There is a checkbox for languages. Whenever a language gets checked, several custom fields for that language get added (i.e. title, cover image, isbn).

When displaying the content of a "book", I'd like to loop through my custom fields and display the one's that belong together in a collapsible panel.
Here is what I have so far:

```
           <?php $fields = get_field_objects();
             if ($fields): ?>
             <ul>
              <?php
                foreach ($fields as $name => $field):
                  if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                     <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Deutsch/<?php echo substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1); ?></button>
                     <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                     <?php //isbn
                        echo $field['prepend'] . " " . $field['value']; ?> </br>
                        <?php echo the_field('titel_'.substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1)); ?>

                      </div>

                   <?php endif;
                 endforeach; ?>
                 </ul>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

the buttons for the collapse are displaying the correct data (i.e. Deutsch/Englisch, Deutsch/Arabisch) but the title and ISBN both belong to the first language displayed.

I would appreciate any hints!

the var_dump() of the $fields variable: **EDIT** removed the var_dump since it was way too big!

**Edit**

Here is the update of my code: It's now displaying the correct fields and data, but I don't know how to put it in the collapsible panel..

```
 <b>Erhältlich in den folgenden Sprachausgaben:</b>

        <?php
        $fields = get_field_objects();
        if ($fields): ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            foreach ($fields as $name => $field): ?>

                <?php //hoerprobe
                if (get_field('horprobe_verfuegbar') == 1) :
                    if (stripos($name, 'hoerprobe') !== false) : ?>
                        <?php echo $field['label'];
                        $file = get_field($name); ?>
                        <audio controls>
                            <source src="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>">
                            Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                        </audio>
                        </br>

                    <?php endif;
                else :
                    // echo 'false';
                endif; ?>

                <?php
                if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                        Deutsch/<?php echo substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1); ?></button>

                    <?php //isbn
                    echo $field['prepend'] . " " . $field['value']; ?> </br>

                    <?php //titel
                    echo the_field('titel_' . substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_") + 1)); ?> </br>

                    <?php //coverimage
                    $titelbild = get_field('titelbild_' . substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_") + 1)); ?>
                    <?php if ($titelbild) : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $titelbild['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $titelbild['alt']; ?>"/>
                    <?php endif; ?></br>
                <?php endif;
            endforeach;
        endif; ?>
```

when adding this

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
                       ...</div>
```

no matter which button I click, it's only opening the data for the first language..

**Edit 2**

Audio file is nor working inside the collapse panel. Here is how it works:

```
 <b>Erhältlich in den folgenden Sprachausgaben:</b>

        <?php
        $fields = get_field_objects();
        if ($fields): ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            foreach ($fields as $name => $field): ?>

                <?php //hoerprobe

                if (get_field('horprobe_verfuegbar') == 1) :

                    if (stripos($name, 'hoerprobe') !== false) : ?>

                        <?php echo $field['label'];
                        $file = get_field($name); ?>
                        <audio controls>
                            <source src="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>">
                            Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                        </audio>
                        </br>

                    <?php endif;
                else :
                    // echo 'false';
                endif; ?>
                <?php
                if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                    <?php $lang = substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_")); ?>
                    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $lang ?>">
                        Deutsch/<?php echo substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1); ?> </button>

                    <div id="demo<?php echo $lang ?>" class="collapse">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor text....

                        <?php //isbn
                        echo $field['prepend'] . " " . $field['value']; ?> </br>

                        <?php //titel
                        echo the_field('titel_' . substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_") + 1)); ?> </br>

                        <?php //coverimage
                        $titelbild = get_field('titelbild_' . substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_") + 1)); ?>
                        <?php if ($titelbild) : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $titelbild['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $titelbild['alt']; ?>"/>
                        <?php endif; ?></br>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;
            endforeach;
        endif; ?>
```

but as soon as I move the **hoerprobe** part inside the collapse panel, it's not displaying it anymore..

Comment: could you post values inside $fields. will be better to use this echo "<pre>"; 
 print_r($fields); 
echo "/<pre>";

Comment: sorry I don'T know what you mean or where it'S leading me?

Comment: Are you able to show us the values in the $fields array? For example by using var_dump($fields); This might help shed some light on the problem? Possibly what @LatheeshVMVilla was asking for?

Comment: sure! It's a pretty long dump, so I don't know if I should just post it all.. I'll add it to my post @junkrig

Comment: In dump I see for example `$fields["titel_arabisch"]` item, but you are trying get `<?php echo the_field('titel_Arabisch'); ?>`.  Maybe it should be `echo the_field('titel_'.substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_") + 1))`

Comment: @nmr yeah thanks, I just realized this as well!! I will update my post with the code I have now. It's displaying the correct fields/data now, but I can't get it work in the collapsible panel.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You display data in loop, so all item have the same ID `div id="demo"`. Add some suffix to make them unique. For example:

```
$lang = substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_");

echo '<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo-'. $lang .'"> ....';

echo '<div id="demo-'. $lang .'" class="collapse"> ...</div>'
```

**Edit**

Audio doesn't work inside the collapse panel because key `$name` never meets both conditions:

```
if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false): 
   if (stripos($name, 'hoerprobe') !== false)
```

`$name` is either **hoerprobe_arabisch** or **isbn_arabisch**.

Try this code:

```
if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
   <?php $lang = substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_")); ?>
   <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $lang ?>">
      Deutsch/<?php echo substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1); ?> </button>

    <div id="demo<?php echo $lang ?>" class="collapse">
         Lorem ipsum dolor text....

       <?php //isbn
          echo $field['prepend'] . " " . $field['value']; ?> </br>

       <?php //titel
          echo the_field('titel'. $lang); ?> </br>

       <?php //coverimage
          $titelbild = get_field('titelbild' . $lang); ?>
          <?php if ($titelbild) : ?>
              <img src="<?php echo $titelbild['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $titelbild['alt']; ?>"/>
          <?php endif; ?></br>

       if (isset($fields['hoerprobe_'.$lang])) : ?>

           <?php
           $hoerprobe_field_name = 'hoerprobe'.$lang;
           $hoerprobe_field = $fields[$hoerprobe_field_name ];
           echo $hoerprobe_field['label'];
           $file = get_field(hoerprobe_field_name); ?>

           <audio controls>
               <source src="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>">
                    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
               </audio></br>
       <?php endif;

    </div>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: awesome thank you so much! Now everything is working the way I want except for the audio file. For some reason I can't put it in the collapse panel. It's only working outside the panel.. I added my code, do you see where the problem is?